# Should I save image binary data to database or save images as files?

Tags: database, image

I have program that saves unique images that are related to unique database fields to database as binary fields or save in folders as image files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you need to do with the images, how often you access them and how often they change.

There is no right answer for this one - it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Images are big in size, for example 500k-1mb

Comment: Doesn't matter. How many images are you talking about? What are the usage scenarios?

Comment: One image is approximately loaded 5-10 times per session

Comment: You can always save the image data to the filesystem first time it is called and pick it up from there (and if `! File.Exists(path)` refetch from DB.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use a distinct key/value storage if available. This can be hosted by your own or something like Amazon S3. If not, better save the images as files and organize meta data and path information in your database.